# Присвоить картинке новый путь

Tags: javascript, jquery

почему не работает?

```
$(".constructor .result_category .get_list[data-id='"+parent_d+"']").closest(".ln").find(".vib_img").attr("src") = imag;
```

Answer (score 4):

Следует использовать так:

```
.attr( attributeName, value )
```

Ваш случай:

```
$(".constructor .result_category .get_list[data-id='"+parent_d+"']").closest(".ln").find(".vib_img").attr("src", imag);
```

[Документация по .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)